# how to get deals between two date range in Pipedrive api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pipedrive-api

I am integrating third party api called Pipedrive .

I want to get all deals between the date range. The date range is dynamic i.e. given by user.

For eg. if I select date 2017-01-2 to 2017-01-20 then I want all deals between that date range.

I also tried https://github.com/GeneralScripting/pipedrive-ruby gem , but not getting proper result.

How can I get it.

Comment: Not really familiar with the API, but according to the API, selecting Deals by Date Range doesn't seem to be possible: https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1#methods-Deals

Comment: @leifg In your link there is only one api that provide me date range filter but it return open and won deal .